# await is only valid in async function error for a async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I am fetching 2 URLs at the same time using ***Promise all*** but when I am calling this function using await (as getAllURLs is async function) it gives me an error, How can I solve this problem?

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

let urls = ["https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users","https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"]

async function getAllUrls(urls) {
  try {
    var data = await Promise.all(
      urls.map((url) => fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()))
    );

    return data;

  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    throw error;
  }
}


const response = await getAllUrls(urls) 
console.log(response)
```

Error :

```
 let responses = await getAllUrls(urls)

 await is only valid in async function
```

Comment: Please [search](/search?q=await+only+valid+in+async) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only call `await` inside an `async` function, for example:

```
(async () => {
  const response = await getAllUrls(urls) 
  console.log(response)
)()
```

Alternatively, you can use a JS engine or compiler with top-level `await` support.

Comment: I am getting [AsyncFunction] as output when I am using above code

Comment: The output of what?